# Debian stretch is Stretched

Tags: linux, debian, resolution, stretch

I am using the latest version of Debian, Debian Stretch. Yesterday I found a hidden folder. I opened it and it made my screen turn black since it's screen was in fullscreen, so I closed it and then it made my computer freeze. So then I restarted it and logged back in. When I did so my screen was completely stretched out, and I tried fixing it but couldn't do so. Thankful for response, and if I forgot to add some details to it, let me know.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. You need to add a lot more details. What do you mean by you opened the hidden folder? Did you try to edit it, open it in a file manager,  open it in a web browser, cd to the directory from a shell, or what? What was the name of the hidden folder?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what the hidden folder was, and I guess I was just curious about it. It might've been an .exe file that I used Wine to run with. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody here will be able to figure out what the folder was, so just focus on fixing the display.  It sounds like the resolution got changed to something other than the native resolution.  If you know the screen resolution and the screen is at least usable as is, you might be able to reset the resolution in the system configuration menu.  Otherwise, see kostix's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the display so botched you can't operate normal GUI there, do this:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to drop into the first so-called "virtual console" (VC)—a textual screen.

   You'll be presented with a login prompt.
   Enter your user name, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be prompted with the password.
   Enter the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get logged in—you'll
   be put into a normal Unix shell (no GUI, just command prompt).
2. Run there:

   ```
   xrandr --display :0
   ```

   to get the list of supported video modes on your GUI head.
   It looks something like this:

   ```
   ~% xrandr --display :0
   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
   VGA-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
      1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
      1280x960      75.04  
      1152x864      75.00  
      1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
      832x624       74.55  
      800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
      640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
      720x400       70.08  
   HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```
3. If you know the native size (X×Y) of your monitor
   (assuming you're using LCD or a TV set flat panel (LVDS)),
   just select it and run

   ```
   xrandr --display :0 --size 1280x1024
   ```

   Otherwise try some sensible number.
4. Switch back to GUI screen by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
   (because the GUI screen is typically run on the virtual console #3).

   If it won't work, try different <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys
   while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> down—until some will work.

   > If you feel like hacker, run
   >
   > ```
   > ps a -o tty,cmd | grep Xorg
   > ```
   >
   > and see on which TTY the X.org server (that piece of software doing GUI
   >   screens on GNU/Linux systems) runs on—say, if the output lists
   >   `tty6`, you'd need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
   >   to get there.

If this won't fix the problem, we'll need more info.
The first thing to do then is to put the contents of the file
`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` into some [pastebin site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) and provide a link to that snippet.
We'd also probably need the output of `lspci -v` in that form as well.

Please also note that such questions are better asked on
[the `debian-user` mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user)
because the format of StackExchange sites do not usually imply several
back-and-forth exchange of information,—they are for questions which can be answered right away.